# Are aggregates and aggregate roots implemented as separate classes?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

With so much talk about DDD, I've expected to find lot of code examples how these patterns are implemented. But wasn't so lucky.

What confuses me is this. Is an aggregate kind of entity, represented as aggregate root, or are those implemented as separate classes? Here are few examples, please answer if any of them is true.

1. They are separate classes

```
class Aggregate {
   private Entity aggregateRootEntity;
   //methods that keep invariants
}
```

2. There is no separate aggregate class, but aggregate root class, which represents the aggregate

```
class AggregateRootEntity {
   //id, fields, value objects references, other entities references
   //methods that keep invariants
}
```

3. Any entity can be an aggregate, if it is used in transaction scope, keeps invariants, and "aggregates" some value objects

```
//This is aggregate:
class Entity {
   private List<ValueObject> valueObjects;
   //id, fields
   //methods that keep invariants
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is no separate aggregate class, but aggregate root class, which represents the aggregate

This one.

The reference book that introduced DDD, and the "aggregate" pattern, is Eric Evans [Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity int the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00794TAUG).

Chapter 5 discusses patterns used in modeling a domain in software: entities, values, "domain services", and so on.

Chapter 6 discusses *life cycle management*, where he talks about factories, repositories, and aggregates:

> An AGGREGATE is a cluster of of associated objects we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.  Each aggregate has a root and a boundary.  The boundary defines what is inside the aggregate.  The root is a single, specific ENTITY contained in the aggregate.  The root is the only member of the AGGREGATE that outside objects are allowed to hold references to....

If you like, an aggregate is a *graph* of objects, which includes the root object, and the other objects that you can reach from the root object by traversing local references.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please one more, just to clarify completely: So classes for aggregate roots and regular entities don't have any special properties to distinguish them (like for entities and value objects presence of ID), but it's their role that makes the difference, not the code?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  In some examples, you'll see an empty "marker interface" used to distinguish roots.